# After Javascript Validation page redirect to another page

Tags: javascript

i have tryed to validate textbox using javascript.when i click on the submit button without inserting values to textbox it's display alert box.but after click on "ok" button , page redirect to payments.php page.how to fix it

```
<form method="post" action="payments.php"  >
                First Name : <br />
                 <input name="name" type="text" class="ed" id="name"  /> <br />

                E-mail : <br />
                <input name="email" type="text" class="ed" id="email"  />  <br />


                <input name="but" type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="Validation()" />
            </form>


function Validation()
{

if (checkFName()&&checkemail())
    {

   window.event.returnValue = false;
     }
}

function checkFName()
     {
var tname = document.getElementById("name").value;
if((tname == null)||(tname == ""))
{
   alert("Please Enter your First name");
return false;
}
return true;
}


 function checkemail()
  {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var ap = email.indexOf("@");
  var dp = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if((ap < 1)||(dp-ap < 1)||(dp >= email.length-1))
  {
  alert("invalid email address");
  return false;
  }
  else
  return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CONFIRM button type to "button":

```
<input name="but" type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="Validation()" />
```

Give your form a name:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="payments.php">
```

then in your Validation() function, if your form passes validation, you can do the following:

```
function Validation()
{
    if (checkFName()&&checkemail())
    {
        document.forms["frm"].submit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Fiddle proof please . . . I think there's more wrong with his code than that.